# Error while using cql connect

Tags: python-2.7, cassandra, cql

```
con = cql.connect(host="127.0.0.1",port=9160,keyspace="my_keyspace",cql_version='3.0.0')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cql/connection.py", line 143, in connect
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cql/connection.py", line 63, in __init__
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cql/thrifteries.py", line 177, in set_initial_keyspace
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cql/cursor.py", line 80, in execute
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cql/thrifteries.py", line 77, in get_response
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cql/thrifteries.py", line 98, in handle_cql_execution_errors
```

cql.apivalues.ProgrammingError: Bad Request: You have not logged in

I am very new to cassandra,please let me know what wrong am i doing here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cql, if you go to the home page, it says this is deprecated https://code.google.com/archive/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-dbapi2

I would recommend using cassandra-driver
https://datastax.github.io/python-driver

Answer (score 0):

Go to `\var\log\cassandra` there you must find `system.log` file. There you should see an error